# Send unsigned document to signer through Docusign API

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using Docusign APIs, in PHP. so when every a new request came it will generate the Document in Docusign and email will be sent. but many times customer do not sign at that time due to many reasons like not available on desktop or low connectivity on mobile.

1. I wanted a way via API to send that Document to Signer to complete it.
2. Many times, they wanted to get the Document to another email id, can I change the Signer Email provided earlier in envelope and send it again.

Code help will be more helpful.

Comment: Just as a heads up, claiming something is urgent is a [**bad idea**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest); people are actually *less* likely to answer questions claiming to be urgent. To everyone but you, your question is no more urgent than any other. Some might even see it as coming off as arrogant in thinking you're more important than other people who come to StackOverflow with problems. And as you say, code would be helpful, yet you have provided none of your own, making it *very* difficult to help.

Comment: Could not understand the 1st qs, what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second qs, is yes. You can use DS APIs to correct signer's email, you can use [Update Recipient API Call](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) to update the recipient and also send an email notification as well.